# Existence of a potential function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given some function $v\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$, how can we check whether there exists a function $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R})$ such that $v = \nabla f$?

I believe the existence of such a $f$ was equivalent to some other statement that's easier to check, but I can't recall exactly what it was, nor can I find it on Google.

Comment: $\text{curl} v=0$ is such a condition.

Comment: Ok, can you quote the name of a theorem that says that? How do we then compute $f$?